# Как посчитать арифметическое выражение, записанное в строке, с помощью подзапросов Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Дана произвольная строка, состоящая из чисел разделённых заданными одинаковыми арифметическими операторами (только «+» или только «-»). Требуется вычислить математическое выражение, записанное таким образом.

Примеры:

Исходная строка: '12+9+45+61'
Результат: 127

Исходная строка: '1-12-3'
Результат: -14

Важно, что при решении нельзя использовать регулярные выражения, циклы, иерархические запросы и тому подобные вещи. Можно использовать подзапросы (без рекурсии) и функции со строками.

Насколько я понимаю, необходимо разделить числа, входящие в исходную строку и записать их в разные строки, а затем можно выполнить суммирование по значениям в этих строках. Но как это сделать без цикла?

Answer (score 3):

Простое решение с функциями со строками - написать свою функцию, принимающую символьное выражение и возвращающую результат его выполнения.

Например (на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9302d16d45a3f9ba667f1dd71f6899f8)):

```
create table t (id, expr) as
    select 1, '12+9+45+61' from dual union all
    select 2, '1-12-3'     from dual;

with function eval (expr varchar2) return number is
    res number;
begin
    execute immediate 'begin :r := '||expr||'; end;' using out res;
    return res;
end;
select expr, eval (expr)
from t;
```

Результат:

```
EXPR       EVAL(EXPR)
---------- ----------
12+9+45+61        127
1-12-3            -14
```

Comment: Такое решение не подходит, потому что здесь написано решение с помощью создания своей функции, такие конструкции нельзя использовать по условию

Comment: Почему нельзя написать свою функцию? Где это у вас в условии написано? Такое у вас: _Можно использовать ... и функции со строками_.

Answer (score 0):

Вот какое решение удовлетворяет всем условиям и решает поставленную задачу

```
UNDEFINE str

WITH symb_id AS 
(SELECT *
 FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN LTRIM(REPLACE('&&str',' '),'-') LIKE '%+%' 
                   THEN '+'||LTRIM(REPLACE('&str',' '),'-')||'+' 
                   ELSE '-'||LTRIM(REPLACE('&str',' '),'-')||'-' END nstr
       FROM dual) nstr 
 JOIN (SELECT ROWNUM numb FROM all_objects) numb 
 ON SUBSTR(nstr.nstr, numb.numb, 1) IN ('+', '-'))
 
SELECT '&str' "String", 
SUM(CASE WHEN ROWNUM = 1 
         THEN CASE WHEN REPLACE('&str',' ') LIKE '-%' 
                   THEN -ABS(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(nstr, id1, id2-id1))) 
                   ELSE ABS(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(nstr, id1, id2-id1))) END 
         ELSE TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(nstr, id1, id2-id1)) END) "Result"
FROM(SELECT id1.nstr, id1.numb id1, min(id2.numb) id2 
     FROM symb_id id1 JOIN symb_id id2 
     ON id1.numb < id2.numb 
     GROUP BY id1.numb, id1.nstr 
     ORDER BY id1);
```